# CSS font-size in @media query does not change back after rotating

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a toolbar at the top of my web site with some image and text links. I want the font size of the text links to change in response to a screen size smaller than 400px. I have achieved this using an @media query as per the source below. It works, but the problem is with rotation on a phone. If the page is loaded portrait the @media query applies and the text changes size. When rotated to landscape, the @media query rules are all correctly removed. When rotating back to portrait, all of the @media query rules except the font-size are re-applied. This means the text is too big. I have taken a screen capture to show this working:

https://i.imgur.com/TEYORH1.mp4

I can provide more code if needed, but I can't provide a link to the site at this point. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
/* CSS */

.toplinks {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    .toplinks {
        font-size:15px;
        text-align:left;
        padding-left:60px;
        font-family: 'Avenir Next Demi';
    }
}

/* HTML */

<div class='footercell toplinks'>
    <a href='albums.php' style='pointer-events:auto; '>ALBUMS</a> | <a href='singles.php' style='pointer-events:auto; '>SINGLES</a> | <a href='/epk' style='pointer-events:auto; '>EPK</a>            
</div>
```

Comment: It does however work correctly on a desktop browser when resizing the window; the font size changes back and back again along with all the other rules in the @media query

Comment: did you try to specify orientation ?

@media (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 399px)

Comment: @Foxlab - just tried it and it behaved the same way. The problem doesn't seem to be with the query being selected as the text-align, padding-left and font-family properties change back on rotation in either direction, it's only the font-size property that gets stuck

Comment: Ok, so other ideas :) 
Did you try with other smartphone system/browser, like android/chrome (I can see on you video this is IOS) ?
Did you try to use a system font instead of 'Avenir Next Demi' ?
Did you try to specify font-size with relative values like EM or REM ?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas man. I don't have another phone OS I can test with but can try on a friend's android phone at some point. However it does the same thing in both Brave and Safari. I tried removing the font tags from both the normal state and the media query, and the font changed to Times New Roman but the issue with the font size remained. I haven't tried using relative sizes. I have never done it, but I will try now

Comment: Ok I tried using `font-size:0.5em` in the media query and it's better, but the font size is smaller when the page first loads in portrait than it is after rotating to landscape and then back to portrait

Comment: `font-size:0.5rem` did the same thing too

Comment: Sorry man, unless somebody has another pure CSS idea, I think you'll have to make some JS workaround ...
By the way to test with other smartphones you can use the chrome debugger tool, it's not exactly the same behavior but it's close.

Comment: No worries bud, I appreciate your suggestions. I hadn't thought of using JS. Detecting viewport change is trivial in JQuery IIRC so I'll have a look into it. Thanks again man

Comment: Ok so it does it even without the media query in the stylesheet, and even if I don't specify the size of the font in that element at all. iOS seems to mess with the font size on rotation. I'll probably end up creating SVG images for each of the links so I can control the size more precisely, which is frustrating

Comment: I found this snippet which is I think related to your problem:

`/* Prevents Mobile Safari from bumping up font sizes in landscape */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

@Foxlab helped me try a few things which ultimately let me to realise that it was nothing to do with the media query. Even with this removed, iOS decides to resize the text on rotation and rotation back, even if I don't specify this behaviour. This seems so unreliable that in the end I converted all of the text links to SVG images of the text so they scale without issue. I can set the height of the images in their CSS class, and adjust the size in a media query based on the width of the screen as before. But now, using images, iOS respects the sizes I specified and doesn't change it to what it thinks it should be. It's annoying having to do it this way, but at least it works.

Edit: expected behaviour, now working with images instead of text: https://i.imgur.com/s7xQOTp.mp4

Comment: Thanks for the post of your solution, I bet it will help some guys with same IOS problem :)

Comment: There's another possible solution in the comments on the OP made by @Adam P, which might allow for the use of text-based links. I need to give this a try and if it works I'll ask Adam to post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. In the meantime, this works :)